# Azure Custom Template Deployment Options

Tags: windows, azure

I have a web application that I deploy over and over again but in different Azure environments.  The WIndows VM itself does not change (I install the webapp and it connects to a SQL Database).

What I am looking for is 
1.  How do I make a template of the entire setup (VM and then SQL Server)?  I know I can make the templates based upon the VM code but how do I actually install the App first and make that a Gold Disk?
2.  The web app generated a X509 certificate each time, so that other servers if they connect can communicate security, is there a way to automate this process each time?

Thanks, I really am newer to Azure deployments so I am just getting my feet wet.

Comment: Have you thought about using an Azure Web App and Azure SQL (both PaaS services) instead of deploying to a VM?  This way you don't have to worry about installing IIS or SQL, you just deploy your code and database.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are vm images with sql server already installed, so you dont have to install it, you only have to configure your database. That can be done with Azure PowerShell DSC extension: you can configure your server like any other. You can invoke that extension from the template.
2. Not sure what you mean exactly, I think you can create webapp certificate from the arm template, but any webapp got a certificate by default so you dont really need that (questionmark).
3. Not sure about the gold disk you mention, you mean gold image? you can use something like packer to do that, but I usually just use arm templates to create\configure vm.